# Xamarin.Forms protected OnAppearing method - how to change bool value?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In one of my pages in Xamarin.Forms app I want to detect, when OnAppearing method is called first time.

I try to do this by add bool value, which when page is initializing is set to true, but when OnAppearing is called, the value is set to false.

How it looks in code:

```
public partial class ListPage : ContentPage
{

    bool FirstLoad = true;

    public ListPage()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        Debug.WriteLine("***** OnAppearing ListPage");

        if (FirstLoad)
        {

            //Do something
            Debug.WriteLine("***** FirstLoad = true ");

        }
        else
        {
            //Do something else
            Debug.WriteLine("***** FirstLoad = false ");
        }

        FirstLoad = false;

    }
```

But it's not working. Always, when I activate page it returns me bool value as true.

```
[0:] ***** OnAppearing ListPage
[0:] ***** FirstLoad = true 
[0:] ***** OnAppearing ListPage
[0:] ***** FirstLoad = true 
[0:] ***** OnAppearing ListPage
[0:] ***** FirstLoad = true 
[0:] ***** OnAppearing ListPage
[0:] ***** FirstLoad = true
```

I think the issue is that, the OnAppearing method is protected, but is there any way to handle with this?

@Diego, thank you for your commitment.

MainPage is my MasterDetailPage.

I've created a grid in Lables and Images which have TapGestureRecognizers handlers:

```
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Menu" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White"/>
            <!--<Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />-->
            <Image Source="vehicles.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="40" IsOpaque="True">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="ImgVehiclesTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Label x:Name="LblVehiclesPage" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Pojazdy" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="LblVehiclesPageTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <Image Source="list.png" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="45" IsOpaque="True">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="ImgListTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Label x:Name="LblListPage" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Text="Lista" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="LblListPageTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <Image Source="scheduler.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="50" IsOpaque="True">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="ImgSchedulerTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Label x:Name="LblSchedulerPage" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="Kalendarz" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="LblSchedulerPageTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <Image Source="gmaps.png" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="40" IsOpaque="True">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="ImgMapTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Label x:Name="LblMapPage" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="Mapa" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        Tapped="LblMapPageTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
```

(I don't want to use ListView, because performance will be worse at the startup).

In MainPage ctor, I've intialized ListPage as Detail:

```
Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ListPage)));
```

Also, use this code, in TapGestureRecognizers f.e - VehiclesPage:

```
        private void LblVehiclesPageTapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Detail = new NavigationPage(new VehiclesPage());

        Detail = ((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(VehiclesPage)));
        IsPresented = false;
    }
```

I expect, that all of my pages will upload on startup. And, when I navigate to this page via MasterPage it will be in memory, and then I can properly use OnAppearing method.

Also, I've tried to initialize pages from class, f.e

```
    public class MasterPageItem
    {
         public string Title { get; set; }
         public string Icon { get; set; }
         public Type TargetType { get; set; }
    }
```

But, don't know how can I properly use this.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "activate" page?  If you push this page onto the NavigationStack and then pop it from the NavigationStack, then the Page is destroyed along with all state (need to understand what kind of navigation is causing the output above).

Comment: @gannaway Ok... that could be the point. I have MasterDetail Page, which Master is my MenuPage and Details Page which is f.e. ListPage. To navigate I'm using this code:
Detail = new NavigationPage(new ListPage());
IsPresented = false;

Comment: Ok, so if you are creating a new ListPage each time, then that would explain it.

Comment: @gannaway is right. Each call is creating a new page with the initial property's states. Maybe the point where you have to control the 'first load' is on the menu item click, for example keeping some list of key-value pair for each [page type]-[first load state] pair...

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza what example you have on mind? I'm stuck at this point.

I've created MasterPageItem class, and instantiate it in constructor of MainPage like this:
var page1 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 1", Icon = "itemIcon1.png", TargetType = typeof(ListPage) };

but don't know how to use it when tap on any label and navigate to specific page.

Comment: @MateuszSzafraniec please, include it on your question. I'll post the piece of code to handle it from there as an answer.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza I've updated first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a overall first load, you can set the property as `static`:

```
private static bool firstLoad = true;
```

Once it is set for the very first time, it will stay `false` in all newly created instances.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. In OnApearing method I always have false value.

Comment: Sorry, I switched the values. I have now updated my answer. The field must be `true` in the beginning and you will set it to `false` after first run

Comment: Great :-). If it solved the problem, please consider marking the answer as solution :-)